# publish in twitter from application android

Tags: android, twitter

Hi 
I installed api twitter4j. I want to publish a message on twitter. How can I use twitter4j to publish? If anyone know another api more better can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your Twitter object set up this is update yoru status:

```
Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statusStr);
```

You should do that from a background thread since it is a web activity, so it doesn't freeze the UI. And you should catch and handle the possible exceptions.